# React Query dynamic incremental queries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rest, react-query

I am currently fetching data from a 3rd party api in a React application.

The way the api is structured, the flow goes like this:

```
// Get a list of data
response = GET /reviews

while response.data.nextPageUrl is not null
   response = GET ${response.data.nextPageUrl}
```

I currently have this logic inside of a "fetch method"

```js
const fetchMyData = () => {
  // The logic above
}

const query = useQuery(['myKey'], () => fetchMyData, {...})
```

This works, but comes with some drawbacks.

1. There is no way to see the progress of the individual requests (to be used in a progress bar)
2. It cannot leverage React Query's caching functionality on an individual request.
   For example: If there are 10 requests to be made, but during the 5th request the user refreshes the page, they will need to restart from the beginning.

I am aware of `useQueries` but since I do not know the query urls until I have received the first request I do not see how I could use it.

Is there a better approach or way to satisfy the 2 issues above?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Is caching not enabled on the API?

Comment: @inf3rno no unfortunately, I do not have control over this API either.

Caching individual responses is important because the response times for each individual api call is quite slow :/

Comment: Isn't it possible to add some sort of caching HTTP proxy to your system? I would rather go to that direction if possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Infinite Queries](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/infinite-queries). `useInfiniteQuery` works similar to `useQuery` but it's made for fetching by chunks. `useInfiniteQuery` has extra parameters like `getNextPageParam` which you will use to tell React Query how to determine the next page. This hook also returns  `fetchNextPage, hasNextPage` (among others), which will allow you to implement patterns like a "show more" button that appears for as long as there is a next page.

By using infinite queries you still leverage on React Query caching. Check the docs for more info.